# How to use JMeter to performance test using a laptop systems connected to a VPN instead of the internet

Tags: jmeter

I would like to test the send/receive metrics when connected via a VPN using the JMeter tool then compare the results when not connected to the VPN. Would appreciate any thoughts on this subject.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions Dimitri! I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is something you have to do from JMeter perspective as traffic routing is the job for the VPN client so it should be sufficient just to execute the test 2 times:

- 1 test when the VPN connection is down
- 2 test when the VPN connection is up

The results can be compared using [Merge Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/)

If for some reason your VPN client doesn't pick up the traffic from JMeter to your application due to its configuration you can force JMeter to use your VPN network interface as the source IP address, the setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration element

[image]